# When an edit is started within the grace period of a previous own edit, the edit message field should be prepopulated

Tags: feature-request, edits, edit-summary, grace-period

Sample scenario:

1. Make an edit to a question; perhaps improve its title. Write in the edit message:

   > Please use a descriptive title for your post, even if that makes it spoilery
2. Notice the question tagging also need editing; open the edit page again, retag and write an edit message:

   > Also please only use the 'spoiler' tag only if a question has spoilers in the title
3. Commit the two edits within 5 minutes of the other.

The result is one edit to both the title and the tags with edit message:

> Also please only use the 'spoiler' tag only if a question has spoilers in the title

While being able to change edit messages within the grace window, this behaviour is quite obscure. It would be clearer if, upon loading the edit page at step 2, the edit message field was already filled in with the edit message from step 1 - this makes it clearer that you're changing the field, rather than adding to it.